# which one gives better performance in Tomcat, Jboss AS, Glassfish?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jboss, glassfish

I am about to launch an application. I am using just structs and not even springs in the application. So, at this stage, I would like to know what would give the better performance out of Tomcat, Jboss AS and Glassfish for deploying my applications. And I need to use the Linux (RHEL 6.x) environment as the OS.

Please let me know if any other components that are being used in my application should be brought to your notice for getting an idea on the best tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat is web server/container, and where as JBoss and Glassfish are application servers with much more capability.

And also most of the application servers use 'Tomcat' as base HTTP server. So based on your application requirement and budget select one.

For a basic structs application, I would use 'Tomcat' for better performance.